# php access error using credentials that work in another script

Tags: php, mysql

I'm an iOS developer trying to update a bit 'o php to work with the mysqli_* stuff instead of the deprecated mysql_* stuff.

I know next to nothing about php/mysql, and I'm stuck. I'm using a script found at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp, with changes to reflect my field names etc

When I call the following from a browser I get an access error (Connection failed: Access denied for user 'whoisit7'@'localhost' (using password: YES)). The server name, password and username etc I'm using all work with an existing script in a browser but not with this new one.

Can anyone point me at what I'm getting wrong?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$userName = "whoisit7_ios";
$password = "blahblahblah";
$dbName = "whoisit7_scathing";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT name, latitude, longitude FROM location where status = 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "name: " . $row["name"]. " - latlong: " . $row["latitude"]. " " . $row["longitude"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Use the same caps in the variables always, the variables in PHP are case sensitive: `$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);` here you have `$username` but before you defined `$userName`.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, variable names are case-sensitive. So, Change your connection variable names to:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "whoisit7_ios";
$password   = "blahblahblah";
$dbname     = "whoisit7_scathing";
```

**Read it if you are new to PHP:** http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Answer (score 0):

Php is case sensitive, so change the below line from:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

to

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $userName, $password, $dbName);
```

You have made error in $username which is $userName and $dbname which should be $dbName as you declared above.

Comment: Hanging my head in shame. Soooo embarrassing. Thanks a heap!

Answer (score 0):

Just change -->

1. localhost to 127.0.0.1  //you need to change params in mysql config if u want to use it as localhost

And

2. $username to $userName          //As u need to keep these variables similar :)

Answer (score 0):

this Problem seems to be coming from database privileges as i have also have encountered this before. Give this fix a try.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name TO usernamehere@host IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Just change the lower case letters to your own credentials.